# Eloquent query for emails with reviewers where all reviewers have approval_status have approved the email

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

This query is super close, but it's setting an `approvalStatus` to true based on the most recent review, whereas I want to check all reviews and only set the status to true if all reviews with an `approver_status` set to true have approved the email. An email can have many reviews, some reviewers are approvers and some can only give feedback, but cannot approve/deny. Here's the current query:

```
$emailsWithReviews = Email::with('emailReviews')
            ->where(['created_by' => $personID, 'sent_at' => null])
            ->get()
            ->map(function ($email) {
                foreach ($email->emailReviews as $review) {
                    if ($review->approver_status === true && $review->approved === false) {
                        return $email->approvalStatus = false;
                    }
                    $email->approvalStatus = true;
                }

                return $email;
            });
```

I was thinking the foreach would take care of this, but it's definitely returning true if the most recent is `$review->approver_status == 1 && $review->approved == 1`.

Comment: Would you like to do the same using raw query ?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this might work, you're nearly there with the foreach, but instead of using foreach, try using `filter()` to return any valid reviews that have been rejected, and seeing if the end collection is empty.

For example, if you have 2 reviews by valid reviewers, one accepts and one rejects, find all the reviews that have been rejected, and return whether any have been found.

```
Email::with('emailReviews')
    ->where(['created_by' => $personID, 'sent_at' => null])
    ->get()
    ->filter(function ($email) {
        return $email->emailReviews->filter(function ($review) {
            return $review->approver_status == 1
                && $review->approved == 0;
        })->isEmpty();
    })
    ->each(function ($email) {
        $email->approvalStatus = true;

        // Optionally:
        $email->save();
    });
```

Or if you were worried about performance:

```
$ids = Email::with('emailReviews')
    ->where(['created_by' => $personID, 'sent_at' => null])
    ->get()
    ->filter(function ($email) {
        return $email->emailReviews->filter(function ($review) {
            return $review->approver_status == 1
                && $review->approved == 0;
        })->isEmpty();
    })->pluck('id');

Email::whereIn('id', $ids)->update([
    'approvalStatus' => 1,
]);
```

I'd also be tempted to extract the where conditions into scopes to make it a little easier to read:

```
Email::with('emailReviews')
    ->whereAuthor($personID)
    ->whereNotSent()
    ...
```

Comment: How would I set that to `$email->approvalStatus`?

Comment: That first query sets the approval status for every email to true, despite the fact that none of the data that I'm working with right now should return true.

Comment: Is there a set number of reviews an email must have? or must it have at least 1 accept review, with no reject reviews?

Comment: Nope. An email can have as many reviews as the user would like, though it does need to have at least one "approver". The "non-approvers" are optional for getting more feedback. So you could create an email with one approver and ten non-approvers, or 10 approvers and zero non-approvers.

Comment: It also returns an empty array if any of the reviews of a $review->approver_status as true and $review->approved as false 

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think the issue was that I was daisy chaining to many statements. I solved this by breaking it up:

```
$emailsWithReviews = Email::with('emailReviews')
            ->whereNull('sent_at')
            ->get();

    $emailsWithReviews->filter(function ($email) {
            return $email->emailReviews->filter(function ($review) {
                return $review->approver_status == 1
                    && $review->approved == 0;
            })->isEmpty();
        })
        ->each(function ($email) {
            $email->approvalStatus = true;
        });
```